# How to prevent range Calendar dont't show current date

Tags: java, android, kotlin, calendar

I have a date range Calendar, everything works.
But when I set a range that not include current date,
the current date look like enable(Althout it can not be clicked)
How to make text color be grey.

[image]

today is 11/24, how to make the text color grey just like others can't be clicked

```
private fun showDatePicker() {

        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.time = Date(currentStartDate.toTimeStamp())

        val currentYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val currentMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val currentDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

        val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(context, { _, year, month, day ->
            currentStartDate = "$year-${month + 1}-$day"
            viewBinding.startDate.text = currentStartDate
        }, currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay)

        datePickerDialog.datePicker.maxDate = maxDate
        datePickerDialog.datePicker.minDate = minDate
        datePickerDialog.show()
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked current date section here https://m2.material.io/components/date-pickers/android#anatomy-and-key-properties if it helps??

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks for comments. But how to change the text color or get the view?

Comment: i would try the options in the link first. view belongs to the library so you can have a look at https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/tree/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/datepicker. I am not sure i have not tried it myself. But why would you want to grey out current data that would give an indication of the current date relative to other selected or greyed out dates